# Is there a way of sharing a google.maps.Map instance using web workers?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web-worker

Since workers do not have access to window or DOM elements, is it possible to have multiple web workers doing stuff on the same google maps instance?

The use case: a real-time map visualisation where each worker would plot and move a marker (or set of markers).

Comment: I can't see why not - why don't you try it?

Comment: Haven't tried but I think you can access map instance but cannot move markers on the map, since it is DOM access.

Comment: How can I access the map instance from multiple workers at first? Using transferable objects might not even be doable because they are no longer available once they are passed to the worker context. Is there anything like lockers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I use with Web Workers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495227/what-can-i-use-with-web-workers)