# Is there anyway to make cordova worked inside a web worker?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-worker

My need is I want to access to a sqlite db (like I could do with websql or indexeddb) through the Cordova-SQLitePlugin inside a Web worker. I can't import 'cordova.js' inside a web worker because of 'window' dependency.
One solution could use postMessage and ask main thread to perform queries and get back result but it doesn't seems ideal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I use with Web Workers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495227/what-can-i-use-with-web-workers)

Comment: I have same problem here, when do the select on the sqlite it stuck the UI