# Is there a way to play audio in a mobile web application while a phone is in sleep mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, web-applications

I was looking at web workers which seem capable of giving notifications while a device is in sleep mode.

Are there any current technologies available to play audio in sleep mode?

Relevant link on web-workers
[What can I use with Web Workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495227/what-can-i-use-with-web-workers)