# Unable to create Web Worker from inside webworker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Using Chrome 17.0.963.46 m, I tried to create a new web worker from inside a web worker. But got a "Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined"

Any info. on this? (Google throw surprisingly few links on creating web worker inside webworkers)

Comment: For anyone coming to this question nested workers were added in chrome version 69 and they were not available before
https://chromestatus.com/feature/6080438103703552

Answer (score 1):

That is the current state even on Chrome 19 - here is the bug:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666
It's working on FF.

Answer (score 1):

Creating workers within workers is not available in chrome. FF implemented this with the Example.

See the link for Example and Chroem bug.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Worker/Functions_available_to_workers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers

Example specified by Mozilla Developer network.

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/workers/fibonacci/

Chroem BUg

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666