# Can I access document cookie on web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Though `document` is not accessible from web worker can i access some how the cookie? unless i send a `postMessage` to main thread to give me cookie and it will send it via another `postMessage`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can access neither cookies [nor `localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6179159/607407) ("*local cookies*").

Apart from using `postMessage`, you could also send a AJAX request to server to get/set a cookie. This is in no way more optimal of course - it will take way longer.

Comment: or session storage either. Best to use IndexedDB