# who can kindly tell me why I can't use sessionStorage in SharedWorker?

Tags: html, web

I need to use shared worker to get some status from host, So I use sharedworker in my code.

I want to set sessionStorage in the worker js after it get status from my host like this sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
But after using it, the worker js seems blocked and without any result.
when I comment it ( sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value') ) out, it seems works.

So, Who can kindly tell me is it possible to set sessionStorage in a shared worker? 
Many thanks in advance!

The result I find is that:
In my worker js: typeof(sessionStorage) === "undefined", why?

Comment: In my worker js, the sessionStorage is undef;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker

Comment: find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker/6179599#6179599

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker/6179599#6179599

Comment: Seem's we can't access web storage in web worker.
More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker/6179599#6179599