# How to use localstorage.setItem() inside service worker?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am using type script for my app and i need to store some id's on service worker, but it is not supporting `self.localStorage.setItem('notificationclicked', 'bgclicked')`

Comment: You can't access local storage from service worker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access localStorage from service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887635/access-localstorage-from-service-worker)

Comment: Hi Aleksey , do you know any work around for this?   Actually i need to handle background notification click  on my PWA app to display a different page.

Comment: You can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope/postMessage)

Answer (score 3):

Synchronous APIs like localStorage, XHR as well as the DOM are not accessible in the service worker.

For storage you will need to use IndexedDB. It is not the easiest API to use directly. Instead I recommend a library that can make it as easy to use as localStorage.

I like localForage, https://localforage.github.io/localForage/

Comment: Hi chris ,thank you for your reply but the localForge not working on service worker. Have you used it on the service worker?

Comment: Yes I have. I think I used it in my PWA book.