# Need to access browser local storage in web worker

Tags: javascript, multithreading, local-storage, angular5, web-worker

I have a scenario where i need to use setItem(key,value) method of browser local storage inside web worker . Could anyone of please let me know if there is any way to use the setItem method?

Comment: The `localStorage` is  `undefined` in a webworker process also the `sessionStorage`, you cant

Comment: Thanks Muhammad , could you please guide on any other similar option available that can be used instead?

Comment: see this it might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localStorage from a webWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker)

Comment: you might have to go for [**`IndexedDB`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)